# Sending acknowledgment message to the server via fifo to distinguish clients, clients don't get after messages

Tags: c, client-server, fifo

I have a server and two different clients. Server and clients will comunicate between them via FIFO. Each client first send to server a struct variable which contains clientpid and a number. Number serves to distinguish client. Then server makes adeguate fifo's for each client. After establishing this, server sends a different message to each client. When i run server and clients, client's don't get the message, they hang on read. Why it's happening and what should i do to fix it? (For this example, i simplified the clients, they're allmost the same, except the number that they pass to the server to distinguish themselves. In the original program two client will be doing different things and they will receive different data from server, that's why i need to distinguish them.)

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define ec_neg1(s,m) if((s) == -1) {perror(m); exit(errno);}

#define SERVER_FIFO_NAME "fifo_server"
#define PERM_FILE        0664

struct acknow_
{
 pid_t clientpid;
 int num;
};


int make_fifo_name(pid_t pid, char *name, size_t name_max)
{
 snprintf(name, name_max, "fifo%ld", (long)pid);
 return 0;
} 


int main()
{
 int fd_server;
 int fd_send;
 int fd_recv;
 ssize_t nread;
 struct acknow_ acknow;

 char fifo_send[100];
 char fifo_recv[100];

 char msg1[100] = "SENDER GOT THE MESSAGE\n";
 char msg2[100] = "RECEIVER GOT THE MESSAGE\n";

 printf("server is started\n");

 if(mkfifo(SERVER_FIFO_NAME, PERM_FILE) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
  {perror("can't make fifo"); exit(errno); }

  ec_neg1( fd_server = open(SERVER_FIFO_NAME, O_RDWR), "cant open fd_server" )

  while(1)
  {
    ec_neg1( nread = read(fd_server, &acknow, sizeof(acknow)), "can't read from fd_server")
    if (nread == 0) 
    {
      errno = ENETDOWN;
      perror("nread == 0"); exit(errno);
    }

    if(acknow.num == 1) /* sender's pid arrived first */
    {

      /*MAKE FIFO OF THE SENDER*/
      make_fifo_name(acknow.clientpid, fifo_send, sizeof(fifo_send));

      ec_neg1(fd_send = open(fifo_send, O_WRONLY), "can't open fifo_send" )

      /*GET PID OF THE RECEIVER*/  
      ec_neg1( nread = read(fd_server, &acknow, sizeof(acknow)), "can't read from fd_server")

      if (nread == 0) 
      {
        errno = ENETDOWN;
        perror("nread == 0"); exit(errno);
      }


      /*MAKE FIFO OF THE RECEIVER*/
      make_fifo_name(acknow.clientpid, fifo_recv, sizeof(fifo_recv));

      ec_neg1( fd_recv = open(fifo_recv, O_WRONLY), "can't open fifo_recv" )

    }
    else /* receiver's pid arrived first */
    {

      /*MAKE FIFO OF THE SENDER*/
      make_fifo_name(acknow.clientpid, fifo_recv, sizeof(fifo_recv));

      ec_neg1(fd_recv = open(fifo_recv, O_WRONLY), "can't open fifo_recv" )

      /*GET PID OF THE RECEIVER*/  
      ec_neg1( nread = read(fd_server, &acknow, sizeof(acknow)), "can't read from fd_server")

      if (nread == 0) 
      {
        errno = ENETDOWN;
        perror("nread == 0"); exit(errno);
      }

      /*MAKE FIFO OF THE RECEIVER*/
      make_fifo_name(acknow.clientpid, fifo_send, sizeof(fifo_send));

      ec_neg1( fd_send = open(fifo_send, O_WRONLY), "can't open fifo_name" )


    }

    printf("sending message to sender\n");
    ec_neg1( write(fd_send, &msg1, sizeof(msg1)), "can't write to fd_send" )
    printf("sending message to receiver\n");
    ec_neg1( write(fd_recv, &msg2, sizeof(msg2)), "can't write to fd_recv")

    ec_neg1( close(fd_send), "can't close fd_send" )
    ec_neg1( close(fd_recv), "can't close fd_recv" )

    printf("done\n");
 }

  ec_neg1( close(fd_server), "can't close fd_server" ) 



 return 0;
}
```

Client1.c (here i post only Client1, Client2 is simply the same code, just change the "acknow.num " to the "2" if you want to run them.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



#define ec_neg1(s,m) if((s) == -1) {perror(m); exit(errno);}

#define SERVER_FIFO_NAME "fifo_server"
#define PERM_FILE        0664


struct acknow_
{
 pid_t clientpid;
 int num;
};


int make_fifo_name(pid_t pid, char *name, size_t name_max)
{
snprintf(name, name_max, "fifo%ld", (long)pid);
return 0;
}


int main()
{

int fd_server, fd_client;
ssize_t nread;
char fifo_name[100];
char msg[100];
struct acknow_ acknow;


printf("client1 started\n");

acknow.clientpid = getpid();
acknow.num = 1;


make_fifo_name(acknow.clientpid, fifo_name, sizeof(fifo_name));

if (mkfifo(fifo_name, PERM_FILE) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
  {perror("can't make fifo"); exit(errno); }

ec_neg1( fd_server = open(SERVER_FIFO_NAME, O_WRONLY), "can't open fd_server" )

ec_neg1( write(fd_server, &acknow, sizeof(acknow)),"can't write to fd_server" )

ec_neg1( fd_client = open(fifo_name, O_RDWR), "can't open fifo_name"  )


while((nread = read(0, &msg, sizeof(msg))))
{

  write(1, msg, nread);

}

if (nread == 0) 
{
  errno = ENETDOWN;
  perror("nread == 0"); exit(errno);
}
if (nread == -1) 
 perror("can't read"); exit(errno);



 ec_neg1( close(fd_server), "can't close fd_server" )
 ec_neg1( close(fd_client), "can't close fd_client" )
 ec_neg1( unlink(fifo_name), "can't unlink fifo_name" )


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say "Then server makes adeguate fifo's for each client." I don't think that's true. The server only makes one FIFO. The clients appear to make their own FIFOs.

Comment: @abligh, yes you're right, it opens clients' fifos, i just expressed it wrong.

Comment: solved! it doesn't work just because in the client, i read from stdin instead of pipe! sorry, it was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in the server, you are opening the read FIFO `O_WRONLY`. This should be `O_RDONLY`.

Secondly, in the client, you are opening the read FIFO `O_RDWR`. I believe this is undefined behaviour under POSIX (you don't mention an OS) and should be `O_RDONLY`. That's enough to be getting on with.

Comment: I think you get it wrong. Server writes to client's fifo, not read from it. Client writes to server's fifo. WRONLY is ok. RDWR is not a standard but since i'm on linux and protability not an issue for this example, it's ok. It serves to block read of its fifo until something is written there by the server(you can check it on the book "UNIX Advanced Programming"). Anyway, i also tried as you said, and it gives me "bad file description" error for fd_server. With my version it doesn't give any error.